# iPhone app crashing in TestFlight, working fine in simulator and iPhone Devices

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

We are facing very strange issue in our app.

Issue:

1. App is working fine in simulator and iPhones.
2. Only crashing in TestFlight version.

Here are code snippets which are crashing app:

Creating custom uitableviewcell for the UITableView:

Created cell UI in storyboard

UITableViewCell class code

```
import UIKit

    class SocialMediaNewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText: UILabel!
    
  
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postTimeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

We are using cell object in cellForRowAt method in class UIViewController.

Here is the cellForRowAt method body.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SocialMediaNewCell") as! SocialMediaNewCell
    cell.userNameLbl.text = "XYZ"
    cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Bitmap_4")
    return cell
}
```

Please find the report of crash received from firebase crashalytics:
[image: firebase crash screnshot]

Please check and let us know of anybody is facing the same type of issue.

Comment: Can you buil/run your app as Release? Where is the cell Interface? In a Xib? In Storyboard? How is it registered?

Comment: Hello @Larme

Can you buil/run your app as Release?
We have tried on release app in simulator and its working fine.

Where is the cell Interface?In a Xib?In Storyboard?
In Storyboard

How is it registered?
We have created separate class of UItableviewcell and used that class in cellforRowAt(code already attached in our posted questions).

Comment: You're not giving enough info. The code you've shown is full of exclamation marks, though, and every one of those says "crash me".

Comment: Hello @ matt
Can you suggest anything on firebase report

Comment: If it's crashing on TestFlight, you might also see the issue in Xcode Organizer, it might give you a better pointer. You didn't answer the question on how it's register, if the cell has a xib or is defined in the storyboard. I'm asking, because it seems to call `initWithCoder:` and has a crash, that's why...

Comment: I have the same problem, there are no Storyboards, everything is built programmatically. No crashes show up in TestFlight reports, at least not quickly. @matt point about optionals doesn't help me understand why it works in two environments and not the third.