# App Crashes in TestFlight, Works Fine in Simulator, and on Hardware via Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, testflight

This problem is similar to this question: [iPhone app crashing in TestFlight, working fine in simulator and iPhone Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72111210/iphone-app-crashing-in-testflight-working-fine-in-simulator-and-iphone-devices)
The trail is dead on that one, and I still have the problem.

I have an app that on starting, runs this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("here we go")
        
        CoreDataManager.shared.initialize()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateAfterData(notification:)),
                                               name: oNames.name(.callHomeCompleted), object: nil)
        Tournament.appBuild = UIApplication.build
        Tournament.appRelease = UIApplication.release
        
        print(" \(Tournament.appRelease) \(Tournament.appBuild)")
        _ = Tournament.callHome()
        // return
        createUI()
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
            notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToFront), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        //return
        
        initializeUI()
    }
```

With no changes to this code, this has been working perfectly fine for months, including on production-released app. The routines called are all identical to what was there before, when it was running fine.

Suddenly, however, and while working perfectly fine on the Simulator and on a connected matching iPhone, on TestFlight, it started crashing on startup. Checks of the server log that it connects to showed it never makes that request. adding the "here we go" comment did not show up either in the app logs (on Heroku). A test where the CoreDataManager initialization was run and then the app returned worked fine. The screen was blank, because the UI is built by createUI(). But it seems clear that there is nothing in the pre-viewDidLoad process that is causing a problem.

All that changed was I added a button, that opens a segue to another VC that also tests fine. When that button is not added (the VC was already in place), the problem persists. But again, all that works fine on Simulator and an actual iPhone.

Infuriatingly, a new version sent to AppStoreConnect was declined because I hit the daily upload limit, so I'm waiting a day. Of course, the only reason I hit the limit was the endless troubleshooting particular to this problem....

In any case, the problem is a general one, and I've experienced it once before in this project. TestFlight version crashes, but nothing else does. No crash record in TestFlight. Minor, non-sigificant code chasing, like adding returns at different stages and everything runs ok.... then remove all the return at the last test, and it all works fine...

Someone must have had this problem and know a fix...

Comment: I'd suggest trying to connect the phone to a Mac by cable, launch Console.app, reproduce the crash on device and look into the logs from Console, may be that will give some hints.

Comment: I'm going to have to wait until I can upload again, but there was a crash, the result of not checking the status of the Bearer token... in previous code, that section only got called when login had happened.. we'll see...

Comment: Switch into release build when run with Xcode

Comment: Did you make any change in your core data ? Did you try in on a simulator where it has not been run before ?

Comment: No changes to core data. no changes to any of the routines called at startup. BUT, I think that Bearer token issue may fix it, have to wait til tomorrow to find out....